# MassTransit: How to receive responses returned by multiple consumers

Tags: rabbitmq, servicebus, masstransit

I'm going to use MassTransit with RabbitMQ, and creating Request-Response application. Then I look for how to receive responses returned by multiple consumers.
Is it possible? if it's possible, how can I achieve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [saga](http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/advanced/sagas/automatonymous.html) for this. Request/Reply nature is that the requester waits for reply and then does not wait any longer. All further replies will be ignored.